# Higher voltage output from charger has affected my laptop and burned some components

Tags: power-supply

My computer has been burned by high voltage output from my charger,but my challenge now is that I opened my laptop trying to find which component have been burned but I cannot see the actual component.

I would like to ask which component is most likely to burn first in such a 
situation so that i can know which to replace or in case in need to replace the whole motherboard.

Comment: *"My computer has been burned by high voltage output from my charger"* -- Other than using a charger with a higher voltage, how do you know this?

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer.  If components have actually been damaged, it will require inspection and testing to determine it.